# Converting TFileStream to C#

Tags: c#, delphi, filestream

I've been trying to convert the following Delphi code to C#. I've never worked with Delphi before. I keep running into several errors regarding the `FileStream`.

> Cannot convert from RAMPhdrrec to byte[]
>
> Best overloaded match for Read(byte[], int, int) has some invalid arguments

Also, I'm not able to reference any of the fields in the structure in C#.

Here's the Delphi definition for `TFileStream`:

```
function Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; virtual; abstract;
```

and `C#`:

```
FileStream.Read Method (Byte[], Int32, Int32)
```

How is the Delphi code working with only two parameters?

Delphi code:

```
CONST
   HeaderSize=128;
Type

RAMPhdrrec = packed record
  //Other fields
  FirstRAMPtime: TDateTime;
  LastRAMPTime: TDateTime;
end;

var
  Header:RAMPhdrrec;

Function TestingForm.Testing(PathName:String):Boolean;
StartTime:TDateTime;
   EndTime:TDateTime;
begin
    if RampOpen then
    begin
       RampStream.Free;
    end;
    Try
      RampStream:=TFileStream.Create(PathName,fmOpenReadWrite OR fmShareExclusive );
    except
      ShowMessage(//error message here);
      Testing:=false;
      RampOpen:=False;

    end;
    try
        RampStream.Read(Header,HeaderSize);
        StartTime:=Header.FirstRAMPtime;
        EndTime:=Header.LastRAMPTime;
```

Here's the C#:

```
const int HeaderSize = 128;

public struct RAMPhdrrec
        {
            double FirstRAMPtime;
            double LastRAMPTime;
        }

RAMPhdrrec Header;

public Boolean Testing(string PathName)
        {
            double StartTime, EndTime;

            try
            {
                RampStream = new FileStream(PathName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("//error message here");
                RampOpen = false;
                return false;              
            }

            try
            {
                RampStream.Read(Header, HeaderSize); //error
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: That is not definition of read in delphi: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStream_Read.html It has only 2 params.

Comment: Actually, TStream.Read is overloaded with functions that do and don't expect the Offset argument.

Comment: Ask one question at a time, it is hard to figure out what's up.

Comment: Sorry, I've been using the Delphi.basics website, and it lead me to that definition I gave earlier. I'll edit the post to reflect, thank you.

Comment: Just pass Zero for StartIndex on the C# side, if it lacks the offset-less overload.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and did that. It's saying `Cannot convert RAMPhdrrec to byte[]`. I can make a different question if it's not a quick answer. But RAMPhdrrec is a packed record, not a byte array, and is a struct in my c# code.

Comment: Ah, yes. You can't just bulk-read an array of bytes into a structure in C#. The BitConverter class is your friend.

Comment: Delphi basics? Use the official program docs. For both languages.

Comment: You probable want to use a BinaryReader here. Don't translate literally. Work out what the Delphi code does and write C# code that achieves the same. Blitting packed records is probably not the way forward.

Comment: I've attempted that for most of the code, but I've never done anything related to this before. It's also tough that there are zero comments in the Delphi code and I can't even run the executable/debugger :/ I'm looking into BinaryReader now

Answer (score 0):

I believe this C# code equivalent to Delphi code above.

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(PathName, 
                               FileMode.Open,  
                               FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                               FileShare.None));

StartTime = br.readDouble();
EndTime   = br.readDouble();
```

In Delphi, `System.TDateTime` is alias to `Double` type with integral part is number of days since 12/30/1899 and fractional part is fraction of a 24 hour day that has elapsed. See [TDateTime documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_TDateTime.html). So if you need to convert it to C# DateTime you need convert it manually.

Comment: What if `StartTime` and `EndTime` have other fields in-between them and before/after in the struct?

Comment: What do you mean? StartTime and EndTime are double not struct.

Comment: I should have edited my code, sorry. But those two are fields in the struct, among other ones (I just didn't list them all, there's a bunch).  They are all ints, floats, or doubles.